# biblatex-chicago footnotes end in comma instead of period for articles with no page numbers

Tags: biblatex-chicago

Using the `biblatex-chicago` package, when I cite articles with no page numbers, footnotes end in a comma instead of a period. The references are formatted correctly. Is there a way to fix this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{mwesources.bib}
@article{nopgs,
    author = {John Appleseed},
    journal = {The Journal},
    title = {A Treatise},
    year = {1900}}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{mwesources.bib}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\footcite{nopgs}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE for citation issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `@article` is not the right entry type, since typically a journal article would have a volume and page numbers. But without knowing your exact data, it's not possible to tell what the right entry type is.

I notice that using the `magazine` entry sub type is less strict in its requirements and gives the results you want. However, this still may not be the best setting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{nopgs,
  entrysubtype = {magazine},
  author = {John Appleseed},
  journal = {The Journal},
  title = {A Treatise},
  year = {1900}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
\autocite{nopgs}
\autocite{nopgs}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]